# Change text color for cells using TableGrob

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, gridextra, r-grid

Is there a way to individually change the color of the text of a cell when using tableGrob and ggplot2?

For instance in the code below it'd be great if the cell with 1 could be blue and the cell with 2 could be red, with 3:8 all black.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

mytable = as.table(matrix(c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE))
mytable = tableGrob(mytable,gpar.coretext = gpar(col = "black", cex = 1))
mydf = data.frame(x = 1:10,y = 1:10)

ggplot( mydf, aes(x, y)) + annotation_custom(mytable)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Much to my disappointment, this does not seem to be easy. The `tableGrob` function calls `makeTableGrobs` to layout the grid object and returns a fully calculated `gTree` structure. It would be nice if you could intercept that, change some properties, and continue on; unfortunately the drawing gets done with `gridExtra:::drawDetails.table` and that function insists on calling `makeTableGrobs` again, essentially killing any opportunity for customization.

But it's not impossible. Basically we can create our own version of `drawDetails.table` that doesn't do the reprocessing. Here's the function from `gridExtra` with one added `if` statement at the beginning.

```
drawDetails.table <- function (x, recording = TRUE) 
{
    lg <- if(!is.null(x$lg)) {
        x$lg
    } else {
        with(x, gridExtra:::makeTableGrobs(as.character(as.matrix(d)), 
        rows, cols, NROW(d), NCOL(d), parse, row.just = row.just, 
        col.just = col.just, core.just = core.just, equal.width = equal.width, 
        equal.height = equal.height, gpar.coretext = gpar.coretext, 
        gpar.coltext = gpar.coltext, gpar.rowtext = gpar.rowtext, 
        h.odd.alpha = h.odd.alpha, h.even.alpha = h.even.alpha, 
        v.odd.alpha = v.odd.alpha, v.even.alpha = v.even.alpha, 
        gpar.corefill = gpar.corefill, gpar.rowfill = gpar.rowfill, 
        gpar.colfill = gpar.colfill))
    }
    widthsv <- convertUnit(lg$widths + x$padding.h, "mm", valueOnly = TRUE)
    heightsv <- convertUnit(lg$heights + x$padding.v, "mm", valueOnly = TRUE)
    widthsv[1] <- widthsv[1] * as.numeric(x$show.rownames)
    widths <- unit(widthsv, "mm")
    heightsv[1] <- heightsv[1] * as.numeric(x$show.colnames)
    heights <- unit(heightsv, "mm")
    cells = viewport(name = "table.cells", layout = grid.layout(lg$nrow + 
        1, lg$ncol + 1, widths = widths, heights = heights))
    pushViewport(cells)
    tg <- gridExtra:::arrangeTableGrobs(lg$lgt, lg$lgf, lg$nrow, lg$ncol, 
        lg$widths, lg$heights, show.colnames = x$show.colnames, 
        show.rownames = x$show.rownames, padding.h = x$padding.h, 
        padding.v = x$padding.v, separator = x$separator, show.box = x$show.box, 
        show.vlines = x$show.vlines, show.hlines = x$show.hlines, 
        show.namesep = x$show.namesep, show.csep = x$show.csep, 
        show.rsep = x$show.rsep)
    upViewport()
}
```

By defining this function in the global environment, it will take precedence over the one in `gridExtra`. This will allow us to customize the table before it gets drawn and not have our changes get reset. Here's code to change the colors of the values in the first two rows as you requested.

```
mytable = as.table(matrix(c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE))
mytable = tableGrob(mytable,gpar.coretext = gpar(col = "black", cex = 1))

mytable$lg$lgt[[7]]$gp$col <- "red"
mytable$lg$lgt[[12]]$gp$col <- "blue"

mydf = data.frame(x = 1:10,y = 1:10)
ggplot( mydf, aes(x, y)) + annotation_custom(mytable)
```

And that produces this plot.

[image: table with color]

So the syntax is a bit cryptic, but let me explain with this line

```
mytable$lg$lgt[[7]]$gp$col <- "red"
```

The `mytable` object is really just a decorated list. It has an `lg` item which is what's calculated from `makeTableGrobs` and has all the raw `grid` elements inside. The `lgt` element under that is another list that has all the text layers. For this table, `lgt` has 15 elements. One for each square in the table starting with the "empty" one in the upper left. They go in order top-to-bottom, left-to-right, so the cell with 1 is `[[7]]` in the list. If you run `str(mytable$lg$lgt[[7]])` you can see the properties that make up that text grob. You will also notice a section for `gp` where you can set the color of the text via the `col` element. So we change it from the default "black" to the desired "red".

What we are doing isn't part of the official API so it should be considered a hack and as such may be fragile to future changes in the libraries involved (`ggplot2`,`grid`,`gridExtra`). But hopefully this will at least help you get started in customizing your table.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Just to add for others, you can use this approach to change the background fill as well

    `mytable$lg$lgf[[7]]$gp$fill <- "black"`

Answer (score 14):

With gridExtra >=2.0 aesthetic parameters can be specified via the theme argument, e.g.

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
mytable = as.table(matrix(c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE))

cols <- matrix("black", nrow(mytable), ncol(mytable))
cols[1,1:2] <- c("blue", "red")
tt <- ttheme_default(core=list(fg_params = list(col = cols),
                                bg_params = list(col=NA)),
                      rowhead=list(bg_params = list(col=NA)),
                      colhead=list(bg_params = list(col=NA)))

mytable = tableGrob(mytable, theme = tt)
mydf = data.frame(x = 1:10,y = 1:10)
ggplot( mydf, aes(x, y)) + annotation_custom(mytable)
```

[image]

Alternatively, the [grobs may be edited](https://github.com/baptiste/gridextra/wiki/tableGrob#accessing-existing-grobs-in-the-table) before drawing.

Comment: How would you fill the sell instead of the colour of the font?

Comment: This might be a bit old but I recently encountered the same problem where I want to change the fill of a single cell. The method on https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/tableGrob.html did not work for me, however I found a workaround with Baptiste's code above. change the 

`cols <- matrix("black", nrow(mytable), ncol(mytable))
cols[1,1:2] <- c("blue", "red")` into `fill <- matrix("black", nrow(mytable), ncol(mytable))

fill[1,1:2] <- c("blue", "red")`, then add `fill = fill` in the bg_params = list(col=NA) part of the core will do the work

Comment: "fill" can be specified using @baptiste's code, changing `bg_params = list(col=NA)` to `bg_params = list(fill=cols)`. The `fill=` parameter is not available in `fg_params` (errs) but works in `bg_params`; the `col=` parameter is available in `bg_params` but does not fill the whole cell.

Answer (score 7):

**Edit**

gridExtra >=2.0 was rewritten from scratch, and low-level editing is now possible. I'll leave the old answer below for completeness.

**Original answer**

`grid.table` doesn't allow post-editing of the grob; it should probably be reimplemented using the recent makeContext strategy from the grid package, but that's not very likely to happen.

If you really want a table based on grid graphics, you're probably better off writing your own function. Here's a possible start,

[image]

```
library(gtable)

gt <- function(d, colours="black", fill=NA){

  label_matrix <- as.matrix(d)

  nc <- ncol(label_matrix)
  nr <- nrow(label_matrix)
  n <- nc*nr

  colours <- rep(colours, length.out = n)
  fill <- rep(fill, length.out = n)

  ## text for each cell
  labels <- lapply(seq_len(n), function(ii) 
    textGrob(label_matrix[ii], gp=gpar(col=colours[ii])))
  label_grobs <- matrix(labels, ncol=nc)

  ## define the fill background of cells
  fill <- lapply(seq_len(n), function(ii) 
    rectGrob(gp=gpar(fill=fill[ii])))

  ## some calculations of cell sizes
  row_heights <- function(m){
    do.call(unit.c, apply(m, 1, function(l)
      max(do.call(unit.c, lapply(l, grobHeight)))))
  }

  col_widths <- function(m){
    do.call(unit.c, apply(m, 2, function(l)
      max(do.call(unit.c, lapply(l, grobWidth)))))
  }

  ## place labels in a gtable
  g <- gtable_matrix("table", grobs=label_grobs, 
                     widths=col_widths(label_grobs) + unit(4,"mm"), 
                     heights=row_heights(label_grobs) + unit(4,"mm"))

  ## add the background
  g <- gtable_add_grob(g, fill, t=rep(seq_len(nr), each=nc), 
                        l=rep(seq_len(nc), nr), z=0, name="fill")

  g
}

d <- head(iris, 3)

core <- gt(d, 1:5)
colhead <- gt(t(colnames(d)))
rowhead <- gt(c("", rownames(d)))
g <- rbind(colhead, core, size = "first")
g <- cbind(rowhead, g, size = "last")
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```