# Plot a table where specific rows can be highlighted (gridExtra alternative)

Tags: r, plot

According to this question/answer: [gridExtra Colour different rows with tableGrob](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18414001/1900520), gridExtra does not have the ability to highlight specific rows in the grid.table.

What then can be done to plot a table with specific row highlighting.  Is there a better table package on CRAN?

Is the only solution to build the table up from its component rectangles, lines and labels?

**Edit:**

The output needs to be an image.  I am using `rmarkdown` and html/TeX rendering of markdown tables are inconsistent, and TeX tables are usually too big for good beamer slides, plus you can't control the size (except using `\tiny` etc).  I'm not at liberty to alter the beamer default file, and so the only real work around is to do tables as images, then you can specify the size etc.

Comment: what format? you want the table to be an image?..

Comment: Maybe try [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23820048/2372064). Just replace `mytable$lg$lgt[[7]]$gp$col ` with `mytable$lg$lgf[[7]]$gp$fill` to modify the fill color rather than label text.